# How to save data into database of custom condition in magento 2

Tags: magento2

[image]
How to save custom condition data into databse in magento 2

Answer (score 0):

You need to save conditional data in serialised form in database.

> you need to create database table field like bellow either by
> InstallSchema.php or dbschema.xml

```
       ->addColumn(
            'custom_condition',
            Table::TYPE_TEXT,
            '2M',
            [],
            'Conditions Rule'
        )
```

> than you need to use below code inside your Save.php file

```
        if (isset($data['rule']['conditions'])) {
            $data['conditions'] = $data['rule']['conditions'];
        }

        unset($data['rule']);
```